# How do I go about Mesh Simplifcation in generating multiple LODs?

Tags: optimization, 3d-meshes, mesh, lua, level-of-detail

I have been recently looking for any information on creating multiple LODs (level of detail) for an inputted mesh. However, there does not appear a lot of articles or pseudo code on how to go about how to produce multiple levels.

Any guidance would be very helpful, thank you.

The only information I could find is a Stanford slides but did not go in depth enough

They never show the evaluation.https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/08_Simplification.pdf and I found a paper I been trying, but lots of constants seem to be left out of definition, ex. d [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~garland/Papers/quadric2.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Egarland/Papers/quadric2.pdf)

Comment: Want to link to the slides you want help understanding?

Comment: @DMGregory They never show the evaluation. https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/08_Simplification.pdf

and I found a paper I been trying, but lots of constants seem to be left out of definition, ex. d https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Egarland/Papers/quadric2.pdf

Comment: Please include all the details and clarifications into the questions body )

Comment: @NoahWilliams Is there a specific reason you cant just remove detail in something like blender and load/unload differently detailed meshes in script?

Comment: @Pow I am trying to make myself a tool to do it quicker

Answer (score 0):

Quality LOD meshes are created during the creation process:  "Start small and build upon..."

There is no general automatic solution for the reverse process.

Use the full mesh in all LOD levels.

---

Yes, there are vertex reduction algorithms, see point-cloud triangulation, but they require human correction to look natural.